# Netbeans Jar file not packaging AbsoluteLayout

Tags: java, class, netbeans, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I created a GUI using `AbsoluteLayout` from a Netbeans project.  If I try running the jar the project builds I get an error `NoClassDefFoundError` about the `AbsoluteLayout` class.

Why is that class not available to the jar?  It works when run from within Netbeans, and I expected that the jar it produces would contain everything the project needs.

Comment: I tried to clean up the grammar a bit for you and add some code formating around class names and the like.  I also added the netbeans tag to hopefully attract a wider, helpful audience.

Comment: Also, this is possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586038/jar-doesnt-work-with-absolute-layout

Comment: I went thru this thread before.  How to jar file into your project jar file? No options in Netbeans.   I could only made it work after package as exe.   But that's not what I want.   I still want to know if my original question has an answer.